# Add ggplot pie chart to ggmap map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I've recently tried posting a similar question to this using `rworldmap` but have been advised to attempt `ggmap` instead due to the ease of use in conjunction with `ggplot`.

My question is twofold and my knowledge of R is reasonably basic so please bear with me.

I'd like to overlay pie charts I create in ggplot on to a map. There doesn't necessarily have to be interaction between the two, as long as I can get an image of my pie on top of the map plots.

I have pie charts created using the code:

```
AD_Pie <- 
ggplot(Tally_AD_Sorted, aes(x = "", y = n1, fill = Haplogroup)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, size = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("R1b" = "#7100b0", "R1a" = "#ff9c2c", "E1b" = "#bc67ff", "N1a" = "#94a800", "R1" = "#b1008a", "I2a" = "#d23645", "J2a" = "#fd2e00", "I1" = "#009cf8", "Other" = "#4f574e")) +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(title = "Haplogroup Proportion, >1AD") +
  ggsave("AD_pie2.png", dpi = 1000)
```

This gives me a pie chart with a legend, but I will be removing the legend at some point.

I have also created a map, and have plotted coordinates as points on this map using the code:

```
map <- get_stamenmap(c(left = -24.6, bottom = 20.5, right = 179.0, top = 77.8), size = c(640,640), zoom = 5, maptype = "terrain-background", color = "bw", force = TRUE)
png(file = "AD_Map.png", width = 10, height = 8, units = 'in', res = 800)
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data = Coordinate_AD_Clean2, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = Haplogroup, shape = Haplogroup),
             size = 2,
             stroke = 0) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("R1b",
                               "R1a",
                               "E1b", 
                               "N1a", 
                               "R1", 
                               "I2a", 
                               "J2a", 
                               "I1",
                               "C",
                               "C2", 
                               "G",
                               "G2a",
                               "HIJK", 
                               "I", 
                               "I1a",
                               "I2b", 
                               "IJK", 
                               "J",
                               "J1",
                               "L",
                               "O", 
                               "P~", 
                               "Q1a", 
                               "R"),
                      values = c("#7100b0",
                                "#ff9c2c",
                                "#bc67ff", 
                                "#94a800", 
                                "#b1008a", 
                                "#d23645", 
                                "#fd2e00", 
                                "#009cf8",
                                "#4f574e",
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e",
                                "#4f574e",
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e",
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e",
                                "#4f574e",
                                "#4f574e",
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e", 
                                "#4f574e")) +
  scale_shape_manual(breaks = c("R1b",
                                "R1a",
                                "E1b", 
                                "N1a", 
                                "R1", 
                                "I2a", 
                                "J2a", 
                                "I1",
                                "C",
                                "C2", 
                                "G",
                                "G2a",
                                "HIJK", 
                                "I", 
                                "I1a",
                                "I2b", 
                                "IJK", 
                                "J",
                                "J1",
                                "L",
                                "O", 
                                "P~", 
                                "Q1a", 
                                "R"),
                     values = c(24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                24, 
                                24,
                                24,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21,
                                21))




dev.off()
```

My question is whether it is possible to plot the pie chart I have created in `ggplot` on to the map I have created in `ggmap`. There have been some similar questions on this issue but I have yet to find a definitive or easy to follow answer, so I'm hoping that maybe a more tailored response will help me. I only need to plot my pie chart once, at a reasonable size, on to one map at a certain position.

My second is more of a tidy code question. In my map code I am having to specify a list of colours and shapes manually for each value. Is there any way to make this code simpler?

Thank you for your time, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you can try `geom_scatterpie` from `library(scatterpie)`.

Example from its documentation:

```
library(ggplo2)
library(maps)
library(scatterpie)

# generate dataset
set.seed(123)
long <- rnorm(50, sd=100)
lat <- rnorm(50, sd=50)
d <- data.frame(long=long, lat=lat)
d <- with(d, d[abs(long) < 150 & abs(lat) < 70,])
n <- nrow(d)
d$region <- factor(1:n)
d$A <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=1))
d$B <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=2))
d$C <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=3))
d$D <- abs(rnorm(n, sd=4))
d[1, 4:7] <- d[1, 4:7] * 3
head(d)

# plot
world <- map_data('world')
p <- ggplot(world, aes(long, lat)) +
    geom_map(map=world, aes(map_id=region), fill=NA, color="black") +
    coord_quickmap()
p + geom_scatterpie(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=region, r=radius),
                    data=d, cols=LETTERS[1:4], color=NA, alpha=.8) +
    geom_scatterpie_legend(d$radius, x=-160, y=-55)
```

Which in your case I think it translates to something like this:

First, you have to create your map with, ggmap and assumig your ggmap plot is called `p` then:

```
p +
geom_scatterpie(data=Tally_AD_Sorted,
                aes(x = long, # assuming you have a long column in your df
                    y = lat, # asumming you have a lat column in your df,
                    group= XXXXX) # here goes the name of the column separating your populations or whatever goes in each x,y pie
                    cols= c(XXXX)) # character vector with the name of your haplotypes. This assumes your data is in wide format, and each column is an haplotype. You can use long_format = TRUE if you have your data in long format, but it assumes a column called value exists.
```

You can change colors, fill, etc with the usual ggplot2 tools.